# Permutation and Combination with restrictions

Tags: permutations, combinations

There are 7 chairs.  4 are reserved for men and 2 are reserved for ladies.  Remaining 1 can be occupied by anybody - either a lady or a man.  In how many ways, can 6 men and 3 ladies be seated on these 7 chairs. Thanks.

Comment: Could you tell us what have you tried so far?

Comment: I was on the sameline as @amwhy.  4 men can be seated in 6P4 ways, 3 ladies can be seated in 3P2 ways, and the last seat in 3P1 ways, hence, total number of ways 6P4*3P2*3P1=6480.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  You can seat either four men or five.  For permutations involving four, how many ways are there to seat four men out of six in the four chairs?  Then you seat three women in the other three chairs.  Do the same for five.

Answer (score 1):

First choose the 4 men to sit in the reserved chairs $\binom 64$, multiply by $4!$ since they can sit in any order in those chairs. Then choose the two women to sit in the reserved chairs: $\binom 32$ and multiply by $2!$, since the two can sit in any order in the reserved chairs. Then choose 1 of the remaining 3 persons (one of the remaining two men and one woman) $\binom 31$. There is only one unreserved sit to sit him/her.

In all, that gives us $$\binom 64\cdot 4! \cdot \binom 32 \cdot 2! \cdot \binom 31= 15 \cdot 24 \cdot 3 \cdot 2\cdot 3 = 6480\; \text{ ways to sit them as required.}$$